# mysql insert monitoring

Tags: mysql, monitoring

Please tell me how is it possible to monitor insertion rate per second for a table with mysql ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can monitor it in real time by simply doing something like this

- Count the number of rows
- Wait `x` seconds
- Count the number of rows, find delta `y` between two counts
- `rate = y/x`

If you don't want to do it in real time, you can could parse the [MySQL binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html) to see how many insert statements were executed and obtain their timestamps.

Or you could give each row a timestamp, and then find the average insertion rate for any arbitrary period by counting the rows inserted in that period. For example, to get a count of rows inserted in last hour...

```
SELECT count(*) AS inserted 
FROM table 
WHERE unix_timestamp(created) BETWEEN unix_timestamp()-3600 AND unix_timestamp();
```

Finally, if you want some general graphing of insertions (and other operations) you could use something like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) (though by default this would be tracking all inserts, not just those in a particular table). Here's an example

[image: munin graph example]

Comment: doing a count can be quite expensive (with innodb for instance), writing a bin log, might be see as a performance issue, unless one requires replication anyways ...

Comment: yeah, count(*) on innodb is a pain :(

Comment: +1 for the only answer that was per-table, as the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can periodically do a

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Handler_write'
```

which will give you the amount of insert operations sent to a storage engine. Note that these writes might have failed. But depending on your purpose it might be good enough.